# What is Agora on-premise recording concurrency?

Tags: agora.io, agora-cloud-recording

I'm trying to use Agora on-premise recording. Would like to know what is the concurrency for it? Here is Agora on-premise recording related documentation: https://docs.agora.io/en/Recording/recording_integrate_cpp?platform=Linux